# Как получить неповторяющиеся строки при запросе с подзапросом и с фильтром "IN"

Tags: sql

Есть такая БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить информацию из всех трех таблиц сразу по нескольким uID и при этом добавить поле с суммой всех операций (oSum), где тип операции (oOper) равен CASHIN.

Пробую использовать такой запрос:

```
SELECT uID, aName, (SELECT SUM(oSum) from Opers WHERE ouID IN ('1','2','3','4','5') AND oOper = "CASHIN") as TotalCashin FROM Users LEFT JOIN AddInfo on uID = auID LEFT JOIN Opers on uID = ouID WHERE uID IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Но он возвращает очень много повторяющихся строк, не понимаю почему и как это исправить.

Мне нужно получить такой результат:

```
uID | aName | TotalCashin 
1   | user1 | 100
2   | user2 | 0
3   | user3 | 50
4   | user4 | 1000
5   | user5 | 0
```

Спасибо.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запишем ваш запрос в более понятном виде, отформатировав его:

```sql
SELECT uID, 
       aName,
       (SELECT SUM(oSum) 
        from Opers 
        WHERE ouID IN ('1','2','3','4','5') AND oOper = "CASHIN"
       ) as TotalCashin 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN AddInfo on uID = auID 
LEFT JOIN Opers on uID = ouID 
WHERE uID IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Отсюда сразу видно, что:

- запрос на вычисление `SUM` у вас никак не привязан к остальным запросам, поэтому он будет одинаковый для всех строк выборки, что явно неправильно
- второй `JOIN` я так понимаю присоединяет к каждому пользователю множество операций, их нужно аггрегировать (через тот же `SUM`, например), иначе да, на каждую операцию из `Opers` будет своя отдельная строка и пользователи будут повторяться, если есть несколько операций на одного пользователя

Если я что-то в чём-то понимаю, то запрос видимо должен быть такой:

```sql
SELECT uID, 
       aName,
       SUM(oSum) as TotalCashin 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN AddInfo on uID = auID 
LEFT JOIN Opers on uID = ouID 
WHERE uID IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
GROUP BY uID, aName
```

Может быть нужна ещё будет группировка по `auID`, но тут я не уверен.

Comment: А зачем **LEFT** JOIN? всё равно WHERE его превращает в INNER..

Comment: @Akina Но ведь `WHERE` условие на ту таблицу к которой идёт `JOIN`, а не на ту, которая джойнится, разве оно тут так подействует, как вы написали?

Comment: Да, точно... то-то я по привычке написал, а какое-то неудобство осталось. Не зря рекомендуют люди всем полям алиасы таблиц добавлять.

Comment: @Akina Про алиасы полностью согласен, тут чисто на догадках у меня всё построено - что первая буква в названии поля такая же, как у названия таблицы. Ну, такое, да.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.